# Scichart's setVisibleRange() having no effect

Tags: java, date-range, scichart

I'm trying to set the visible range of a `DateAxis`. Here's what I have:

```
final IXyDataSeries<Date, Double> dataSeries = sciChartBuilder.newXyDataSeries(Date.class, Double.class).build();

final IAxis xBottomAxis = sciChartBuilder.newDateAxis()
       .withAxisId("xBottomAxis")
       .build();

xBottomAxis.setAutoRange(AutoRange.Never);
xBottomAxis.setTextFormatting("MM.dd.yyyy h:mm a");

Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
long t = rightNow.getTimeInMillis();
Date rightNowPlusFiveMin = new Date(t + (5 * ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS));
Date rightNowMinusThreeHr = new Date(t - (3 * ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS));

xBottomAxis.setVisibleRange(new DateRange(rightNowMinusThreeHr, rightNowPlusFiveMin));
```

This *should* keep it from `AutoRanging` and set the default min and max on the `xBottomAxis`. Is this not how you do it?

Currently, it's just `AutoRanging` to fit the data.

Edit: Here are the applicable links for its documentation.

- https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#Axis%20Ranging%20-%20VisibleRange%20and%20DataRange.html
- https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#Axis%20Ranging%20-%20Setting%20and%20Getting%20VisibleRange.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like removing mySciChartSurface.zoomExtents() fixed it. [Link](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/android/v2.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~com.scichart.charting.visuals.ISciChartController~zoomExtents.html) to zoomExtents documentation.

Thanks to Yura Khariton for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to copy-paste your code in [this example](https://www.scichart.com/example/android-mountain-chart-example/) and it worked as expected - axis was rendered with assigned VisibleRange value.

I noticed that you used custom AxisId for your DateAxis. Does it mean that you have more than one XAxis and maybe your RenderableSeries is attached to wrong axis?

Also I would suggest you to update to the latest version of the library  - it could be possible that if it's a bug then it's already fixed in latest build.

If it doesn't help then you'll need to provide more code or entire project which reproduces this issue because with code which you provided it's hard to tell what could be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to take a look at the examples right now to really see how they work. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like removing mySciChartSurface.zoomExtents() fixed it. I have no idea why I didn't notice that earlier... :) Thanks!